# Why do people mark questions as favorites when they haven't even upvoted them?

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes, bookmarks

I've recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014513/check-whether-a-default-deleted-function-template-is-instantiated-for-a-specific) which, within a few days, has garnered 1 upvote, but was marked as favorite by two people.

This post is not about that question, though, it's about the logic behind marking a question as a favorite while not upvoting it (which, in particular, happened with my question). What is the rationale, in general, for doing this?

Comment: Please see [Why do users favorite questions but not vote for them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58647/why-do-users-favorite-questions-but-not-vote-for-them) as well as [If you bookmark a question, shouldn't you also be encouraged to upvote it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/if-you-bookmark-a-question-shouldnt-you-also-be-encouraged-to-upvote-it)

Comment: To be honest i would have closed vote it and given a downvote, when it was on my home turf, Looking for a C++11 solution. is imho not a valid question, and you didn't even try a own solution.

Comment: Only the specific users who favorited the question can tell you why they did so. Maybe they don’t particularly like the question but are interested in what answers it can garner. Personally, I’ve favorited questions by mistake more than once. Also favorited questions to remember to delete vote after those got closed. No idea if that applies here, haven’t visited the question.

Comment: I personally have used favorites to mark poor questions that I think the user has a reasonable chance of improving, to check back later to see if they're in a better state.

Comment: If your favorite hobby is deleting stuff, you favorite a question to check back later to verify if it got roomba-ed already.

Comment: I often favorite questions which I can't figure out at a glance and don't have the time to examine ATM, but don't appear to be *good* (so I don't upvote), so I can come back later to see if there've been answers (and if so, I can upvote if the problem was interesting), or to see if the problem turned out to be a typo or non-reproducible.

Comment: How did you determine the user who favorited your question was the user who issued an upvote?

Comment: @SecurityHound: I didn't. At least one user favorite'd  without upvoting. Usually I can't tell.

Comment: Maybe someone wants to know if any answers comes on it. But they forgot there's voting on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I favorite some duplicate target not easy to find

Comment: "favorite" should be renamed "bookmark" because that's how I use it.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I believe that that’s ready implemented, and will roll out soon; it’s in the pipeline of changes now that “following” has been implemented.

Comment: Why should “favourite” mean “worthy of an upvote”? Some of my favourite questions are those that are terrible examples, but I find them helpful in a “this is what happens when you don’t listen to your elders and betters” sort of way. Favourite != good quality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Webster dictionary definition of favorite: "one that is treated or regarded with special favor or liking." Now, you could say "I like it because it's so bad". But - most users interpret a question being marked favorite as being indicated as exceptionally good or useful. The badges regarding favorites also lend themselves to this interpretation.

Comment: @einpoklum It's unfortunate that the feature is called "favorite". It should be called "bookmark" instead. That's how I used it to come back to posts I downvoted or commented upon to see later if they were improved. Since it's now possible to "follow" a post I'll probably use that instead.

Comment: @ModusTollens: But it were called "bookmarked", it wouldn't make sense to show people how many other users have bookmarked that question. And then I wouldn't wonder about it. And also, there would be no "stellar question" badges.

Comment: @einpoklum I know. It was the only thing we had to bookmark things, so I (and others) used it for that. Things may change now with the "follow" option.

Comment: @einpoklum now you are bringing back your own subjective interpretation again. Now, *good* questions are *more likely* to be favourited (bookmarked) as well, so there is *some* correlation, which is why there are badges for this. But that still doesn’t explain why you *expect* that favouriting equates upvoting. Those two things are entirely separate concepts.

Answer (score 12):

I often use favorites just to mark questions that I, say, need to perform some moderation activity on that requires me to wait a certain amount of time. If I didn't do this, I would easily forget that I was supposed to go back to this question.

As an example, say a question is closed that I want to cast a delete vote on, but I don't have 20K rep yet. I favorite it. When I check my favorites later, I remember that I was going to cast a delete vote on that question.

Comment: And does it not bother you that you're publicly claiming that it is a "favorite" question of yours?

Comment: @einpoklum "favorite" is meant to be used as a tool to find a question. That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: If most users interpret "favorite" literally, and the symbol also indicates something positive, then - publicly, it means it is one of your most liked questions in the whole wide world. Even if you use the favorite mechanism differently.

Comment: @einpoklum So? Who cares? I use it the way I use it. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @einpoklum: don't get stuck on semantics but rather on functionality -- how is the tool being used is much more important than what it is called

Comment: @einpoklum At some point I used "favorite" to remember post of outrageously  low quality for not so positive reasons... It was true "favorite" usage... but definitely nowhere close to what you expect... And indeed I use favorites in the same way as S.S.Anne does - to remember something that require some moderation/attention later. Google/Bing are much better way to have true  "favorite" as "best answer to X" than adding some potentially obsolete question to "favorites"... Maybe with current "follow" feature the "favorite"  usage will simply stop which may align with your expectations.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: But you must understand that the vast majority of users are "stuck on semantics" this way. The see "favorite" and stars, and think that's what it means. So it's somewhat misleading to them. Or, to use a recently popular term, it is (cue dramatic music) **not welcoming**.

Comment: @einpoklum Why not post a feature request to change it then? There already might exist one, no time to investigate right now.

Comment: @einpoklum This is a good resource for beginners as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/686592 It explains that voting is unrelated and what §favorite question" means.

Comment: @ModusTollens: That question has been viewed 36,000 times. Let's be generous and say that only half the views are by regular meta users, and that newbie users only ever viewed it once or never. So, 15,000 out of... what, 2 million people or so, have seen it :-(

Comment: @einpoklum Well, that link was the first entry that popped up when I googled for it, so either users don't search or they don't care a lot...

Comment: @ModusTollens: A large majority of users don't voluntarily visit meta.SO at all; and even from those who do, most don't come across that page. I haven't, for example. I'm saying that the discrepancy between perception by most users and use by a few power users is porblematic.

Comment: @einpoklum I said I searched on Google, not Meta. Look, the discussion here is solving nothing, you got your answer. If you want to change things, post a constructive feature request. But as I see it the problem will solve itself now that the "follow" feature exists. Bye!

Comment: @einpolkum, ModusTollens: Please do not devolve into an off-topic argument on Meta. Instead, go to Chat.